# How do the grids screen out inelastically scattered electrons in low energy electron diffraction

Tags: electrons, low-temperature-physics

This is a wiki article about what I am talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-energy_electron_diffraction.  I was just wondering how the grid screens screen out the inelastically scattered electrons.  I'm confused and would really appreciate some help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inelastically scattered electron will emerge from the sample surface with less energy than the elastically scattered electrons. The voltage on the first grid is tuned so that the inelastically scattered electron will be repelled back towards the sample.

The elastically scattered electrons will be able to pass the first grid, but will lose energy in the process, fighting uphill against the potential of the first grid. While one could let them drift on towards the phosphor, the signal would be very weak since they have little energy. So, the second grid is to re-accelerate those electrons that pass the first grid, resulting in a bright recognizable response on the screen.

Comment: Excellent explanation! I just want to make sure my understanding is correct.  So the electrons (in wave form) diffract from the surface atoms of the sample, then they emerge from the sample (in particle form) and eventually make contact with the phosphor screen (if they have enough energy)?  Also, do you know what causes the electrons to become inelastic?

Comment: First, skip the wave/particle concern - electrons are quantum objects. Their propagation through a crystal can be described using Bloch waves. Now, inelastic scattering events can include things like interactions with lattice defects or impurities. However, the most likely is interactions with the extended electron states of the crystal, where for example you scatter a valence band electron up in to the conduction band (or off plasmons). Clearly, the incident electron loses energy in this process. As such, this is the basis for Electron Energy Loss Spectroscopy, or EELS. See Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Jon's answer is completely correct. I would just like to add that the grid acts as a high-pass filter in the sense that only the inelastically scattered electrons that have a $\Delta E/E$ of about 10-20% will be allowed through the grid. Energies below this threshold will not be allowed to pass.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating.  So in this case $E$ is the electron energy of an elastic electron?

Comment: Yes,  that's correct. Also, inelastic processes occur because the incident electrons can excite quasiparticles such as phonons, plasmons, etc.